# Check if a value still remains the same in a While loop Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop, imperative-programming

I want know if there is a elegant method for looking if a value that continually changes in a while loop can be checked and stop the while loop if the value stops change and remains the same.

For example:

```
Value = 0
while True:
    value changes everytime
    (if value still the same break)
```

Comment: How do you define remains same? like it should match previous iteration value or any value that has taken place yet? Please add some more details to the questions

Comment: You can simply save it into a buffer which will store the value and refresh this buffer on each value change too

Comment: Yes remains the same between more iterations.
The only method is save in a buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this way? BTW: Fix your typo error `while` is not `While` in python.

```
value = 0
while True:
    old_value, value = value, way_to_new_value
    if value == old_value: break
```

Comment: Can you explain how old_value, value = value, way_to_new_value works please?

Comment: Well, the `way_to_new_value` stand for your operation that change the value. The assignment is short for assigning on multi lines.

Comment: Wow it is what I thought then, is impressive this double assignment.

Answer (score 2):

```
previous = None
current = object()
while previous != current:
    previous = current
    current = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A more portable solution would be to make this a class so that an instance holds on to the previous value. I also had a need for a fuzzy match so I included that in the below example.

```
class SamenessObserver:
    """An object for watching a series of values to see if they stay the same.
    If a fuzy match is required maxDeviation may be set to some tolerance.

    >>> myobserver = SamenessObserver(10)
    >>> myobserver.check(9)
    False
    >>> myobserver.check(9)
    True
    >>> myobserver.check(9)
    True
    >>> myobserver.check(10)
    False
    >>> myobserver.check(10)
    True
    >>> myobserver.check(11)
    False
    >>> myobserver = SamenessObserver(10, 1)
    >>> myobserver.check(11)
    True
    >>> myobserver.check(11)
    True
    >>> myobserver.check(10)
    True
    >>> myobserver.check(12)
    False
    >>> myobserver.check(11)
    True
    >>> 

    """

    def __init__(self, initialValue, maxDeviation=0):
        self.current = 0
        self.previous = initialValue
        self.maxDeviation = maxDeviation

    def check(self, value):
        self.current = value
        sameness = (self.previous - self.maxDeviation) <= self.current <= (self.previous + self.maxDeviation)
        self.previous = self.current
        return sameness
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
value_old = 0
value_new = 1
value = [value_old, value_new]
while True:
    # change

    # test
    if value[0] == value[1]:
        break
    else:
        value = [value[1], value[0]]
```